# Hausdorff dimension and critical exponent of words

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, mg.metric-geometry, combinatorics-on-words, hausdorff-dimension

What is the Hausdorff dimension of the subset $S_c \subset [0,1]$ of points such that the [critical exponent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_exponent_of_a_word) of their binary expansion is $c$? It's clear that $\dim_H S_{\infty}=1$, but what can be said for $c<\infty$?. Also, what is $\dim_H \cup_{c\in [2,\infty)} S_c$? Are there techniques for the evaluation of the Hausdorff dimension which are applicable to these cases?

The text by Falconer [1] doesn't seem to cover this kind of questions.

**Update**: it occurred to me that even the estimate of the (upper) box dimension of $S_c$ is not trivial. Already for integer $c$, it leads to a tricky combinatorial problem, that is, how many distinct binary words of length $n$ are there having no factor of the form $w^c$ ($w \in \{0,1\}^*$)?
It's also not easy for me to guess whether the Hausdorff and box dimensions could disagree.

[1]: Falconer, K. (2004). Fractal geometry: mathematical foundations and applications. John Wiley & Sons.

Comment: In the [previous revision](https://mathoverflow.net/revisions/390478/2) you had  "[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_exponent_of_a_word): Falconer, K. (2004)." and most likely you intended to write d"[1]: Falconer, K. (2004)." I have tried to fix this - you can check the source and the [revision history](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/390478/revisions) to see what I changed. You can learn about various ways how links can be formatted [in the editing help](https://mathoverflow.net/editing-help) (the section "Links").

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are a few observations: (the last one is maybe the main point of interest)

$\bullet$ Your $S_c$ is a closed subset of $[0,1]$ invariant under $x \mapsto 2x \pmod 1$ (usually there's a subtlety about points with multiple expansions, but none of those are in $S_c$ for $c < \infty$), and so I think a result of Furstenberg ([1]) shows that it has equal Hausdorff and box dimension. They should both be equal to the topological entropy $h(S_c)$ of $S_c$ viewed as a subshift on $\{0,1\}$ (using $\log_2$ in definition of entropy).

$\bullet$ In [1], Kolpakov proves that $dim(S_3) = h(S_3) \geq 0.5435$ (I've converted to $\log_2$, he used $\ln$)

$\bullet$ for all $c < \infty$, $dim(S_c) = h(S_c) < 1$, since at the least you forbid the word $0^{\lceil c \rceil}$, and all proper subshifts of $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ have entropy less than $1$.

$\bullet$ (this is quite long and probably hard to read, sorry) There are probably better methods, but you can use the techniques of my paper [3] to bound the entropy (and therefore dimension) of $S_c$ from below. Let's restrict to integer $c$ for now. Then $S_c$ is a subshift defined by forbidden list $\{w^c \ : \ w \in \{0,1\}^*\}$, where $w^c$ is the $c$th power of $w$.

The technique from that paper to bound entropy from below is to rescale at some length $j$, and then view your subshift $X$ (here $S_c$) as a new subshift whose alphabet is $A^{(j)} = L_j(X)$ (the set of $j$-letter words in $X$) and whose forbidden list is $F^{(j)}$, a set of forbidden concatenations of `letters' $A^{(j)}$ which induces the same forbidden words as those for $X$. More formally,
$a_1 \ldots a_i$ is in $F^{(j)}$ if the $ij$-letter concatenation $a_1 \ldots a_i$ contains a forbidden word for $X$, but neither $a_1 \ldots a_i-1$ nor $a_2 \ldots a_i$ contains a forbidden word for $X$. This forbidden list $F^{(j)}$ on $A^{(j)}$ induces a subshift $X^{(j)}$ where each point is a sequence of $c$-letter blocks whose concatenation is in $X$. (Formally, $X^{(j)}$ is isomorphic to $X$ under the $c$th power of the shift.)

Here, if we use $X = S_c$ and set $j = c$, then it's easy to bound from above the number of $i$-'letter' words in $F^{(c)}$. There are none for $i = 1$ by definition. For larger $i$, if $a_1 \ldots a_i \in F^{(c)}$, then either $a_1 \ldots a_i$ is a $c$th power of an $i$-letter word (less than $2^i$ possibilities) or contains a $c$th power of an $(i-1)$-letter word ($c$ choices for where in $a_1$ the power starts, less than $2^{i-1}$ possibilities for the base of the power, less than $2^c$ choices for the remaining letters). If only shorter $c$th powers were in $a_1 \ldots a_i$, then one of $a_1 \ldots a_{i-1}$ or $a_2 \ldots a_i$ would contain a $c$th power, disallowed by definition. So, the number of $i$-letter forbidden words in $F^{(c)}$ is less than $2^i + c2^c 2^{i-1} \leq c 2^{c+i}$.

Now, Theorem 4.1 from [3] gives a lower bound for entropy of a subshift. It states that if $X$ is a subshift with alphabet $A$ and an infinite forbidden list $F$ with $F_n$ words of length $n$ for every $n$, and if
$\sum F_i x^i < x(|A| - k + 1) - 1$ for some $x > 1/|A|$ and $k < |A|$, then
$h(X) \geq \log k$. This is hideous, but we can make it easier.

We'll apply to the $c$-letter rescaling $S_c^{(c)}$ of $S_c$ defined above, and assume that $c \leq 10$. Then $|A^{(c)}| = 2^c - 2$ (the only illegal $c$-letter words in $S_c$ are $0^c$ and $1^c$). Let's take $k = 2^{c-1} - 1$ and $x = 4/2^c$. Then $x(|A^{(c)}| - k + 1) = 1$, so we need only verify that
$\sum (F^{(c)})_i x^i < 1$; recall that $(F^{(c)})_i \leq c 2^{c+i}$. Finally,

$\sum_{i = 2}^\infty (F^{(c)})_i x^i \leq \sum_{i=2}^\infty c 2^{c+i} (4/2^c)^i = 
c 2^c \sum_{i=2}^\infty (8/2^c)^i = c 2^c \frac{64/2^{2c}}{1 - (8/2^c)}
= \frac{64c}{2^c-8}$.

This is less than $1$ for $c \leq 10$, so Theorem 4.1 shows that in that case,
$h(S_c^{(c)}) \geq \log k = \log(2^{c-1} - 1)$. But $h(S_c^{(c)}) = c h(S_c)$ (since the former is isomorphic to the latter under the $c$th power of the shift). So, at long last, we get $h(S_c) \geq \frac{\log(2^{c-1} - 1)}{c}$.

In particular, this approaches $1$ as $c \rightarrow \infty$, so this should answer one of your questions: $dim(\bigcup S_c) = 1$.

I should say that I found several papers estimating entropies of $S_c$ from below, and would not at all be surprised if one gives a much easier proof that $dim(\bigcup S_c) = 1$. But all I found were for specific values of $c$.

[1] H. Furstenberg, Disjointness in ergodic theory, minimal sets, and a problem in Diophantine approximation. Math. Systems Theory, 1 (1967)

[2] R. Kolpakov, Efficient lower bounds on the number of repetition-free words. J. Integer Seq. 10 (2007), no. 3

[3] R. Pavlov, Ronnie, On subshifts with slow forbidden word growth.
Ergodic Theory Dynam. Systems 42 (2022), no. 4

Comment: Many thanks for the answer (upvoted, accepted). But why you say that $S_c$ is invariant under multiplication by 2 mod 1? For instance $x=0.11111 \tau \in S_5$ if $\tau$ is the Thue-Morse word, while $2x$ mod 1 $=0.1111\tau \in S_4$. For every $c\in [2,\infty]$, the set $S_{\le c}$ is invariant under that map, though: maybe that's what you meant?

Comment: Cool stuff, I never realized your paper gives like an entropy version of Miller's paper (and surely other results). I think you mean $x(|A^{(c)}| - k + 1) = 2$, as that's what the calculation gives, and that's what you need to apply Theorem 4.1. Also, obviously you mean $c \geq 10$. Also "the only illegal $c$-letter words in $S^c$ are $0^c$ and $1^c$" looks wrong, as you are allowing $c$-repetitions.

Comment: @Alessandro: Invariant in this context (with a non-invertible map) just means $TA \subset A$, not $TA = A$. So since the shift of a sequence which is $c$-power free is $c$-power free, we're OK. 

Also, since I feel my answer is somewhat inscrutable, let me give a briefer summary: it is, in general, difficult to give lower bounds for entropy of non-SFT subshifts unless you can "embed independent behavior," which is hard for $S_c$. But I have a paper which gives, among other things, techniques for bounding entropy only in terms of numbers of forbidden words of each length.

Comment: @Ville: yeah, I really like Miller's paper, and it is indeed the starting point for several arguments in my paper. My results would also show that $S_c$ has a unique MME which is $K$, along with some weak Gibbs bounds. Your first two edits are of course correct, and I'll fix soon. I don't understand the last one; isn't it the case that $0^c$ and $1^c$ are disallowed in $S_c$, and (but I guess this requires proof) all other $c$-letter words are possible?

Comment: @RonniePavlov I meant $TA\subset A$ too. But a point whose expansion is $c$-power free is in $S_{\le c}$, but not necessarily in $S_c$. In my example above  $Tx\notin S_5$.

Comment: Also, I believe you can improve my argument above a lot; using something like $k = 2^c - 2^{.51c}$ and $x = 2/(2^{.51c})$ should still work (since the geometric series starts at $i=2$, it should still converge to a number less than $1$ for large $c$). This would give approximately $h(S_c) \geq \log(2^c - 2^{.51c})/c$, which is on the order of $1 - 2^{-.49c}$.

This is the right general order of convergence, since Doug Lind's perturbations paper shows removing $0^c$ alone drops entropy by roughly $2^{-c}$. The true asymptotics are probably $1 - t^c$ for some $1/2 < t < 1/\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: @Alessandro: Got it! I somehow never noticed that your notation was exponent exactly $c$. Then yes, everywhere I meant $S_{\leq c}$. It seems $S_c$ is not even closed, so my explanation of equal dimension is also (disappointingly) wrong there. I think there is not much literature on sets of sequences with exponent exactly $c$, but it's an interesting question! I will try to edit answer soon for accuracy.

Comment: @RonniePavlov indeed it’s not closed… I was about to ask how to adapt Fustemberg’s result . I thought a bit on an abstract argument allowing a comparison between box and Hausdorff, but it looked far from trivial.

Comment: @RonniePavlov: I think earlier in your answer you disallowed repetitions *more* than $c$, and here you no longer allow $c$. Just a trivial thing.